# INSERT INTO with SELECT using OUTPUT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to store the `pt_id` into my temporary table by using `OUTPUT`, however I'm not inserting `pt_id` into `ct_tarf`, what should I do?

I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier 'pt_id' could not be bound.

Query:

```
DECLARE @tbl_ids_tarf TABLE (pt_id INT, pt_id_tarf INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.ct_tarf(tr_id_serv, tr_name, tr_money)
OUTPUT pt_id, inserted.tr_id INTO @tbl_ids_tarf(ptr_id, ptr_id_tarf)
   SELECT 
      pt_id_serv, pt_name, pt_money
   FROM 
      dbo.opr_prop_tar
   WHERE 
      pt_id_tarf
```

Comment: inserted.pt_id instead of just pt_id

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**SQL2008+:**

Assuming that you want to insert into `@tbl_ids_tarf` (which is target of `OUTPUT ... INTO` clause) values from columns that are not returned by `inserted` or `deleted` virtual tables then one solution is to use [MERGE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead of `INSERT`:

```
DECLARE @Target TABLE (
    Col1 INT
)
INSERT  @Target VALUES (1), (2);

DECLARE @Output TABLE (Col1 INT, ColB INT);

;WITH Source
AS (
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    (VALUES (10, 100), (20, 200), (30, 300)) x(ColA, ColB)
)
MERGE INTO @Target x
USING Source y ON x.Col1 = y.ColA
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (Col1) VALUES (y.ColA)
OUTPUT inserted.Col1, y.ColB INTO @Output (Col1, ColB); 
--                     ^-- y.ColB isn't returned by inserted or deleted virtual tables. 
-- inserted and deleted are based on `@Target` table [variable]

SELECT * FROM @Output;
/*
Col1        ColB
----------- -----------
10          100
20          200
30          300
*/
```

Comment: This answer really misses the point, `MERGE` is overkill for this scenario and better suited for actual _UPSERT_ style queries where you want to `INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE` in a single operation usually because we are _merging_ two datasets, or there are multiple `MATCH` clauses we want to implement. OP was simply trying to capture the `IDENTITY` column value from the insert.

Answer (score 17):

You have several issues with your query - column naming is one, an incomplete `WHERE` clause is another, and a missing `Inserted.` prefix is the third.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl_ids_tarf TABLE (pt_id INT, pt_id_tarf INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.ct_tarf(tr_id_serv, tr_name, tr_money)
OUTPUT inserted.pt_id, inserted.tr_id INTO @tbl_ids_tarf(pt_id, pt_id_tarf)
--     *********                                         ******************
   SELECT 
      pt_id_serv, pt_name, pt_money
   FROM 
      dbo.opr_prop_tar
   WHERE 
      pt_id_tarf --........
```

Comment: I don't this will work .  I tried it and it did not work.  I wonder if anyone had it work for them (especially who voted for this solution).  Give me directions if it did please.

Comment: @Ashi this syntax is correct and will work. MERGE is overkill for this scenario, OP was on the right track, just messed up the syntax. For the nay-sayers... `inserted.pt_id` will be available if that column is an _Identity Column_, which is the general assumption for why OP was trying to capture this value in the first place.